# Angular 2: Custom Directive which detects screen resize

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I want to create a custom directive which can detect the change in browser height and width.

My Directive:

```
        import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, NgZone} from '@angular/core';

        @Directive({ selector: '[resize]' })
        export class ResizeDirective {
            constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
                window.onresize = (e) => {
                    //ngZone.run will help to run change detection
                    this.ngZone.run(() => {
                        console.log("Width: " + window.innerWidth);
                        console.log("Height: " + window.innerHeight);
                    });
                };
            }
        }
```

app.module.ts:

```
            import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA  } from '@angular/core';


            import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
            import { ResizeDirective } from './resize.directive';

            @NgModule({
                imports: [
                    BrowserModule,
                    FormsModule,
                ],
                declarations:
                [AppComponent, ResizeDirectiv],               
                bootstrap: [AppComponent],
                schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]

            })
```

I have placed my directive inside the Body tag of the app.component.html. So whenever the browser screen size changes, I need to perform  specific operation.

app.component.html

```
            <div class="outterContainer" style="width:100%;height:100%;"  resizePlugin>
            <div id="header1" class="header">


            </div>

            <div id="contentSection" class="content">
            <div>
                <div>Resize Demo</div>
                <input [(ngModel)]="studname">{{studname}}
                <createProject></createProject>
                <AddEvent></AddEvent>
                <h2>NavBar + Routing + DragAndDrop + ModalPopup + ReAgrrange Demo</h2>',

            </div>  

            <div>
                <div>
                    <h2>NavBar + Routing + DragAndDrop + ModalPopup Demo</h2>
                    <navbar></navbar>
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there anyway I could modify this directive to make it listen for browser screen size change?

Comment: Angular directives only work within the template of an Angular component. Angular components only work within other Angular components, except these who are listed in `bootstrap: [...]` or the app-module.

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer, I have also tried changing the directive to the app.component.html but it doesn't work. Am I missing anything else ?

Comment: No idea what you mean with "have also tried". Perhaps you can update your question with what you "also tried". If you want to add some Angular stuff here and there to a page that is not built with Angular, Angular is probably not the right framework for you.

Comment: Have you checked if the constructor of the directive gets called?

Comment: Your code seems fine. The size is changed and shows in console. [Plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/BQUvDv4EqooMycvnSq6D/).

Comment: @DracoApollyon Very strange. But it works in plnkr! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it might look like there is a problem with in your directive. angular does not listen for an event that you passed directly angular has a decorator for listening to an event which is @HostListener. Please try below code it might help you

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, NgZone,HostListener} from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({ selector: '[resize]' })
    export class ResizeDirective {
        constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}
        @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
        onResize(event){
                //ngZone.run will help to run change detection
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    console.log("Width: " + window.innerWidth);
                    console.log("Height: " + window.innerHeight);
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Replaced `window.onresize` with `window:resize` and added the missing import for `HostListener` from `@angular/core` and this works like a charm! Also this seems to be the 'angular way'.

Answer (score -1):

you have written **ResizeDirectiv** in your app.component.html, but there is an additional e at the end of the declaration **ResizeDirectiv'*e*'** in your app.module.ts

They need to be the same in order to map.

Comment: Consider editing your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: it's that i write them different ?.